# Mono and Firebird : IOControl Not Implemented

Tags: mono, firebird

I'm actually working on a project where I need to host a .NET webservice on a linux server hosting a firebird database. When I try to run the sample code from http://www.mono-project.com/Firebird_Interbase and call the method, my webservice return me :

```
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.IOControl (IOControlCode ioControlCode, System.Byte[] optionInValue, System.Byte[] optionOutValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.Common.Extensions.SetKeepAlive (System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket, UInt64 time, UInt64 interval) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsConnection.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateManagedDatabase (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionString options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionString options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal:Connect ()
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool:CheckOut ()
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm using the NETProvider-3.1.0.0-MONO_LINUX version of the provider (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/).
Apparently this method is not yet implemented in Mono, but as I don't have the source code, do you have any idea of some workaround ? I'm pretty sure there must be one because if not, this provider made for mono is totaly useless and not tested... :(

Comment: Sources are available on http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/ (or from the main [git repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/NETProvider/ci/master/tree/) or on github on the [account of the .NET provider maintainer](https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution by using the previous version (NETProvider-2.6.5-MONO_LINUX) of the drivers based on [this article](http://mapopa.blogspot.be/2008/09/mono-firebird-example-updated-you-must.html)

What's funny, is that the driver in question is not listed anymore on the official Firebird website... anyway, if you have issue to, try this one from fb sourceforge : [NETProvider-2.6.5-MONO_LINUX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/2.6.5/NETProvider-2.6.5-MONO_LINUX.7z/download)

Comment: You might consider adding this into issue tracker on tracker.firebirdsql.org.